# X-editable simple database update not updating

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, x-editable

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to figure out how the x-editable fields work before I can attempt to implement them in a website. I've seen a couple of examples around the web and even on here but the solutions I've found haven't worked for me. I have an index.php file with a test page that presents two sample fields (text and drop down selector). I was able to get data from a specific table row to show up in the fields. Here's my index.php code.

```html
<?php
 $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "#", "#", "#");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id ='7' ";
 $records=mysqli_query($dbCon,$sql);
 $user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>X-editable Test Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <!-- x-editable (bootstrap version) -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.6/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.6/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
    <!-- main.js -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Sample Editing Page</h1>
      <div>
        <span>Username:</span>
        <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-url="save.php" data-name="username" data-title="Enter username"><?php echo $user['username'];?> </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Country:</span>
        <a href="#" id="country" data-type="select" data-placement="right" data-url="save.php" data-name="country" data-title="Select country"><?php echo $user['country'];?></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I reference a connection.php file:

```html
<?php
    $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "#", "#", "#");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

I am still wrapping my head around the js script and how it gets used. In the "url:" line, I referenced "save.php" which is supposed to update the table data in the database. Here's the js script, which is pretty much taken straight from the example file downloaded from the website:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';  
  
    
    //make username editable
    $('#username').editable({
  type: 'text',
  url: 'save.php',
  pk:7
   
    } 
    );
    
    //make status editable
    $('#country').editable({
        type: 'select',
        title: 'Select status',
        placement: 'right',
        value: 1,
        source: [
            {value: 1, text: 'USA'},
            {value: 2, text: 'Australia'},
            {value: 3, text: 'Other'}
        ]
        /*
        //uncomment these lines to send data on server
  */
        ,pk: 7
        ,url: 'save.php'
    });
});
```

Everything seems to work just fine. The data from the specific row I'm calling (id=7) is showing up just fine. I can click on the field and it becomes an inline editable field. It'll hold the changes I make, but it doesn't stay that way when I reload the page and it doesn't update in the database table. I'm pretty sure that the issue lies in my save.php file:

```html
<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $country=$_POST['country'];
}

$mysql_query= "UPDATE user SET username=$username WHERE id='7'";

?>
```

The version that I have provided here is where I'm at. I've tried at least a dozen different things and then deleted them to try over again. I know this isn't a difficult thing to do, I'm not seeing it yet because I don't fully understand the programming language and its functions, hence why I'm going through this to figure it out. Eventually, this will be implemented in a larger project for a website. I'll worry about the security issues at before I get to that, first I need to figure out to get it working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there's no quote around `$username`. Also, try to always use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) if you're handling user submitted data.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbCon, "UPDATE user SET username=? WHERE id=?");

//'si' stands for String and Integer, respectively for $username and id 7
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $username, 7);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am not seeing where I missed quotes around $username in my code. I haven't really used prepared statements before so I'll need to learn about that. Again, I'm very new to this so I'm still not even sure what all that means. Either way, I implemented your suggestions and I got an "internal server error" when I try to update the user name field.

Comment: I'm assuming `$username` is a string. So, you would have to wrap your variable with quotes, so the database knows it's a string.

Can you check the logs and tell me what is the exact error? :)

Comment: The only thing I can find is that the it says:  "Failed to load resource:http://localhost:8888/edit/save.php the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"